# Is it possible to make a regex that removes each line with more than 2 words

Tags: regex

For example, this is a sample and simplified text file:

word1 word2 word3
word1
word1 word2

word1 word2 word3 word4

I want a regex that could remove anything after the second word, in this instance, word2. And if possible to remove the lines with empty space too. Would something of that sort be possible?

Comment: what tool are you using?

Comment: Perhaps Notepad++ if the regex is simple otherwise I'd say python.

Answer (score 0):

Use Python and the re module:

```
import re

text = """
word1 word2 word3 word1 word1 word2

word1 word2 word3 word4
"""

regex = re.compile(r"\w+\s\w+\s(.*)")
res = re.findall(regex, text)
print(res)
```

Returns:

```
['word3 word1 word1 word2', 'word3 word4']
```

Save to a new file:

```
with open("processed.txt", "w") as wf:
    for r in res:
        wf.write(r)
```

Comment: Looks good, I think it might be a bit sluggish for me because there'd be quite a lot of lines so I'll play around with making it import and export the file without printing the entire results. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, the print step is not necessary. Just compiling the regex, calling findall on your text/file-import, and write the result to a new file is enough

Answer (score 0):

**Note: make sure to make a copy of the file before doing replacements**

regex: `(^\b\w+\b\s\w+)(.*)|^\n`

substitution: `\1`